# Can we use celery as a message consumer (not producer) and distributor?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, message-queue, task-queue

Using `celery`, is it possible to listen for new messages using `RabbitMQ` and schedule worker(s) to process it?

A lot of the `celery` [documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is about using it as a task producer with a broker (say RabbitMQ), where you execute a task and it will be delivered via the broker.

I would like to consume messages from a broker (generated by other services) and process the messages using `celery`.

[image: Broker-Consumer]

Comment: I don't use Celery, but it is my understanding that Celery is a consumer as part of it's purpose of being...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  All you have to do is configure the message that gets put into rabbitMQ in a way that celery recognizes it as a task.  I have done this using Nifi.  I currently use json and the message looks as followed:

`{"expires": null, "utc": true, "args": ["${absolute.path}${filename}", "nifihost"], "chord": null, "callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "taskset": null, "id": "${uuid}", "retries": 0, "task": "taskmanager.tasks.nifi", "timelimit": [null, null], "eta": null, "kwargs": {}}`

I'm not 100% positive which keywords are needed other than the "task" keyword.